# Is there a way to create a struct based on a trait implementation?

Tags: struct, rust, traits, implementation

I'm trying to use a struct with multiple implementations of one method:

```rust
trait Trait { fn apply(&self) -> vec<usize>; }

struct Bar<X> { vec: Vec<usize> }

impl<X> Bar<X> {
    pub fn new(vec: Vec<usize>) -> Self { Self{vec} }
    pub fn test(&self) {
        // Things here
        println!("Method: {:?}", self.apply()); 
        // Things there
    }
}

impl Trait for Bar<ThisWay> {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize> { self.vec.iter().map(|x| x.pow(2)).collect() }
}

impl Trait for Bar<ThatWay> {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize> { self.vec.iter().map(|x| x + 2).collect() }
}

fn main() {
   Bar<ThisWay>::new(vec![1,2,3]).test();
   Bar<ThatWay>::new(vec![1,2,3]).test();
}
```

Which would return:

```
>>> [1,4,9];
>>> [3,4,5];
```

I know I could create 2 structs implementing these methods differently, but that feels wrong as it's potentially a lot of redundant code.
I also know I could have a reference to that implementation method:

```rust
trait Trait { fn apply(vec: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<usize>; }

impl Struct{
    // fn new
    test(&self, t: &impl Trait) {
    // Things here
    println!("{:?}", t::apply(&self.vec));
    // Things there
    }
}
struct ThisWay;
struct ThatWay;
impl Trait for ThisWay {fn apply(vec: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<usize> {///} };
impl Trait for ThatWay {fn apply(vec: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<usize> {///} };
fn main() {
     let this_way = ThisWay{}; 
     let that_way = ThatWay{};
     let problem = Bar::new(vec![1,2,3]);
     problem.test(&this_way);
     problem.test(&that_way);
}
```

This approach seems needlessly complicated when I would want to use many arguments inside given struct:

```rust
fn hill_climber(&self, nullary_op: &impl NullaryOperator, unary_op: &impl UnaryOperator, ...) {
   self.vec = nullary_op();
   self.vec = unary_op(&self.vec, self.n, self.m, self.jobs, self.stuff, ...);
}
```

This seems to be a cursed way of writing code. What happens when a method implementation doesn't use a parameter e.g `m`, and other uses that?

Comment: Do you want to implement `Trait` for anything other than `Bar<X>`? If not, just implement it for `X` instead, and make `apply()` take `&Bar` instead of `&self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traits are used to define shared behaviour. In your example, you want to implement the same trait in different ways. This goes against the purpose of a trait. Instead of having two structs as you tried, you should probably have two traits:

```rust
trait ThisWay {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize>;
}

trait ThatWay {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize>;
}
```

Now you can implement both traits for your struct:

```rust
struct Bar {
    vec: Vec<usize>,
}

impl ThisWay for Bar {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize> {
        self.vec.iter().map(|x| x.pow(2)).collect()
    }
}

impl ThatWay for Bar {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize> {
        self.vec.iter().map(|x| x + 2).collect()
    }
}
```

Because `Bar` implements `ThisWay` and `ThatWay`, it now has two definitions for the `apply` method. To disambiguate between them, we have to use Fully Qualified Syntax:

```rust
let this_bar = Bar::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
println!("Method: {:?}", <Bar as ThisWay>::apply(&this_bar));
    
let that_bar = Bar::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
println!("Method: {:?}", <Bar as ThatWay>::apply(&that_bar));
```

And, as expected, you get two different outputs:

```rust
Method: [1, 4, 9]
Method: [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution to my problem, Thank You, you're my saviour here :D

Comment: @DanielZdancewicz No problem 

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answer, you can also use something more similar to your original example, using generics and zero-sized struct types as "markers" for which method you want to use. Here's a complete example:

```
// PhantomData allows us to "use" a generic without having an actual field
use std::marker::PhantomData;

// These structs will be used to indicate which implementation we want
struct ThisWay;
struct ThatWay;

trait Trait { fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize>; }

struct Bar<X> {
    vec: Vec<usize>,
    // This extra field is here to stop the compiler complaining about not using X
    _marker: PhantomData<X>,
}

impl<X> Bar<X> {
    pub fn new(vec: Vec<usize>) -> Self { Self { vec, _marker: PhantomData } }

    // Note the new "where" clause here - we can only implement this function if Bar<X> implements Trait
    pub fn test(&self) where Self: Trait {
        // Things here
        println!("Method: {:?}", self.apply()); 
        // Things there
    }
}

impl Trait for Bar<ThisWay> {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize> { self.vec.iter().map(|x| x.pow(2)).collect() }
}

impl Trait for Bar<ThatWay> {
    fn apply(&self) -> Vec<usize> { self.vec.iter().map(|x| x + 2).collect() }
}

fn main() {
   Bar::<ThisWay>::new(vec![1,2,3]).test();
   Bar::<ThatWay>::new(vec![1,2,3]).test();
}
```

Running this, the output correctly reflects the different functions being used:

```
Method: [1, 4, 9]
Method: [3, 4, 5]
```

This approach has different semantics from the other answer: whereas the other answer allows you to construct a `Bar` that's capable of being used with both functions, this approach locks you into one implementation at the type level, since `Bar<ThisWay>` and `Bar<ThatWay>` are two separate types that each only provide only one `apply` function. This can be desirable for type safety in some scenarios, but may not be what you need for this particular case.

```
// since x is declared as `Bar<ThatWay>`, we can only ever use the `ThatWay` implementation of `apply`/`test`
let x: Bar<ThatWay> = Bar::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
x.test(); // -> Method: [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, I wondered how to use PhantomData too, cheers